# Vb.net Previsualizar PDF

Tags: pdf

En un winform tengo un DataGridview con varios archivos pdf. La idea es que al pulsar sobre una row, muestre la miniatura del pdf y se actualice cuando cambio de row.
Buscando, encontré dos métodos:

- Con webbrowser. Muestro el primer archivo, pero al cambiar de row, no se refresca, y además al tratarse de Internet Explorer, no sé si tendré problemas en Windows 10.
- Con AxAcroPDF. Carga y refresca bien, pero tarda mucho en cargarse la
  vista previa, y muestra paneles de navegación y firmas digitales.
  Quisiera mostrar exclusivamente el pdf sin paneles ni comprobación de
  firmas. No sé qué me recomendáis, o si alguien conoce otro método.
  Cualquier ayuda será bien recibida.

Comment: Que es lo que has intentado?

Comment: Te sugiero que leas [ask] y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden

Comment: En un winform, estoy tratando de mostrar una miniatura de un pdf. Tengo un listado (en este caso un Datagridview) con los nombres de los pdf, y quisiera previsualizar cada archivo cuando te colocas encima del nombre correspondiente.

Comment: ¿Alguien puede darme alguna pista sobre cómo mostrar la miniatura de un pdf??